# ASP.NET Core 3.0 Docker Container port mapping fails

Tags: docker, asp.net-core

I am trying to get a brand new ASP.NET core MVC web application running from within a Docker container on my windows 10 machine.

I'm no docker expert but the port doesn't seem to get bound on the host. I get a 
response from within the container, but not from the host. The 2.2 sample works fine for me.

```
dotnet --version
3.0.100-preview6-012264
```

Steps to reproduce:

```
mkdir aspnetcore3_test
cd .\aspnetcore3_test\

mkdir aspnetapp
cd .\aspnetapp\

dotnet new mvc

cd ..
dotnet new sln

dotnet sln "aspnetcore3_test.sln" add "aspnetapp/aspnetapp.csproj"
```

Create a docker file with the following content:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.0 AS build
WORKDIR /app

# copy csproj and restore as distinct layers
COPY *.sln .
COPY aspnetapp/*.csproj ./aspnetapp/
RUN dotnet restore ./aspnetapp/*.csproj

# copy everything else and build app
COPY aspnetapp/ ./aspnetapp/
WORKDIR /app/aspnetapp
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o out

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.0 AS runtime
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build /app/aspnetapp/out ./
EXPOSE 80
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "aspnetapp.dll"]
```

Then do the docker bits:

```
docker build -t dockertest .
docker run --rm -it --name=dockertest dockertest:latest -p 80:80
```

Docker run outputs the following:

```
warn: Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.Repositories.FileSystemXmlRepository[60]
      Storing keys in a directory '/root/.aspnet/DataProtection-Keys' that may not be persisted outside of the container. Protected data will be unavailable when container is destroyed.warn: Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.XmlKeyManager[35]
      No XML encryptor configured. Key {5b22d641-4632-4440-8f7d-8ad9b5e48098} may be persisted to storage in unencrypted form.
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Now listening on: http://[::]:80
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Hosting environment: Production
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Content root path: /app
```

With the container running Firefox says that it was unable to connect and `docker port dockertest` comes up empty

`docker exec -i -t dockertest curl localhost` spits out the template MVC app HTML

Comment: Have you tried to map container's port `80` to a less common port on host? For example `8080`.

Comment: @leopal yes I have, same problem unfortunately.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By adding the `-p 80:80` *after* the name of the image, you're actually passing `-p 80:80` as the args for the image executable, rather than as an arg for docker itself. The solution is to move that to *before* the image name:

```
docker run --rm -it --name=dockertest -p 80:80 dockertest:latest
```